# negative reply back by google play about my android app

Tags: android, google-console-developer

after I upload my first app in google play I got a negative reply back and that's the messages I received
And don't know what to do, please help
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the age range when you publish...

it says very clearly that the app is considered to be aimed at children....  make sure that the age range you select includes children...